# Trying to understand what this MySQL table means

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
create table user_roles
(
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
role_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (user_id, role_id),
INDEX(id)
);
```

`user_id` and `role_id` are primary keys of other tables, namely `user` and `roles`. What does `UNIQUE (user_id, role_id),` mean? Does it mean that all `user_id`/`role_id` pairs have to be unique?

And what is `INDEX(user_id)` for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UNIQUE` does indeed ensure that all values that go into the fields differ from the previous.

`INDEX(user_id)` will create an index on the user_id field so that it is better indexed, i.e. it can be searched through faster.

> Without an index, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read through the entire table to find the relevant rows.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Thanks :) We said almost exactly the same thing too!

Comment: I'd like to add that a `UNIQUE` is also an index! So it will also make queries faster that use user_id and role_id to find rows. I think it might even make the other index redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, UNIQUE(user_id, role_id) means that the combination of those two fields for any particular row cannot exist in the table more than once.

INDEX(user_id) applies an index on the user_id column, making searching on that column very fast (at some small performance expense when inserting/updating to the table)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it means that user_id/role_id pairs are unique.